# Heat kernel properties

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm having problem with the heat equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$; specifically in proving the following: let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and: 
$$
u(x,t)=H_{\sqrt{t}}\star f(x)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}\right)f(y) dy
$$
then: $\forall t>0,x\in \mathbb{R}^n, u(t,\cdot)\in C^{\infty}_{0}\cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $u(\cdot,x)\in C^{\infty}_{0}((0,+\infty))$, where $C_{0}$ is the space of all continuos function such that $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}u(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- To show that $u \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ or $|x| \to \infty$, use dominated convergence to move the limit under the integral sign.
- To show that $u$ is integrable, use Fubini's theorem
- To show that $u$ is smooth, use differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Thank for the answer! I'm having trouble in finding a function $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that the absolute value of the integrand is less then g, in order to apply dominated convergence theorem and differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: @Mitch: Hint:$\exp\left(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}\right) \le 1$.  Each of the $x$ and $t$ derivatives of the heat kernel is also bounded in $x$.

Comment: @Mitch: For future reference, you'll get better answers if you include such details (what you tried and where you are stuck) in your original question.